# Find special duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following data in a table

```
   Cust_Code  ItemNo
   ---------  ------
   XYZ        150
   XYZ        100
   ABC        100
   ABC        200
   DEF        100
   etc
```

for a given pair of old `cust_code` and new `cust_code`, I want to select (and delete) duplicates with the following rule: If the newCust_Code has the same ItemNo with the old one, then the old one must be selected/deleted.

Example: if the old cust_code='XYZ' and the new cust_code='ABC' then the second line of the table (XYZ 100) must be deleted as there is already an ABC entry with the same value (100).
I hope I am clear enough.

How can this be done with a T-SQL query?

I declare it in the query by hand:

```
DECLARE @old nvarchar(100) = 'XYZ';
DECLARE @new nvarchar(100) = 'ABC';
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you distinguish old and new codes?  Your description is using names of things that do not appear in the table.

Comment: first: what have you done so far? second: XYZ and ABC have two item codes each. how is that to be handled?

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
with new as (
    select cust_code 
         , itemno
      from tab
     where cust_code = @new
)
delete old
  from tab old
  join new
    on old.itemno = new.itemno
 where old.cust_code = @old
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach putting the logic in the `where` clause:

```
delete from table t
    where t.code = @OLD and
          exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.code = @NEW and t2.itemNo = t.itemNo);
```